# How use C# to export all Onenote pages to mht file

Tags: c#, html, office365, onenote, mhtml

I have an Onenote note, which contains 3 sections and 2 pages for each, i.e. totally there are 6 pages.

How should I write C# code to automatically export all those 6 pages to 6 mht files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OneNote API](https://dev.onenote.com/).

The REST API lets you read the sections, see the notes in them, and export the notes in HTML (with some limitations, like lack of math and handwriting support).

Microsoft provides [code samples](https://github.com/OneNoteDev), you can see if there's anything you can use there.

Answer (score 1):

Jadeson, if your notebooks exist in Office 365 or OneDrive, you may use the service API as Ezhik suggests.  If they do not and you have a Win32 OneNote installation, you may use the OneNote COM API - https://github.com/OneNoteDev/VanillaAddIn.  It is in C# and you can find documentation for that actual APIs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680120.aspx